# Material UI - How to add multiple `actionIcons` to `ImageListItemBar`?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The Material UI documentation for `ImageList` [shows how to add a single](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-image-list/#custom-image-list) `actionIcon` to the `ImageListItemBar`. I copied their code below and added a visualization to show what the `actionIcon` (the white star at the top) looks like:

[image]

How does one add multiple action icons? For instance, suppose I wanted a `like` and `dislike` `IconButton`; how can I implement this?

**Material UI's code:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ImageList from '@mui/material/ImageList';
import ImageListItem from '@mui/material/ImageListItem';
import ImageListItemBar from '@mui/material/ImageListItemBar';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import StarBorderIcon from '@mui/icons-material/StarBorder';

function srcset(image, width, height, rows = 1, cols = 1) {
  return {
    src: `${image}?w=${width * cols}&h=${height * rows}&fit=crop&auto=format`,
    srcSet: `${image}?w=${width * cols}&h=${
      height * rows
    }&fit=crop&auto=format&dpr=2 2x`,
  };
}

export default function CustomImageList() {
  return (
    <ImageList
      sx={{
        width: 500,
        height: 450,
        // Promote the list into its own layer in Chrome. This costs memory, but helps keeping high FPS.
        transform: 'translateZ(0)',
      }}
      rowHeight={200}
      gap={1}
    >
      {itemData.map((item) => {
        const cols = item.featured ? 2 : 1;
        const rows = item.featured ? 2 : 1;

        return (
          <ImageListItem key={item.img} cols={cols} rows={rows}>
            <img
              {...srcset(item.img, 250, 200, rows, cols)}
              alt={item.title}
              loading="lazy"
            />
            <ImageListItemBar
              sx={{
                background:
                  'linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 0%, ' +
                  'rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 70%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)',
              }}
              title={item.title}
              position="top"
              actionIcon={
                <IconButton
                  sx={{ color: 'white' }}
                  aria-label={`star ${item.title}`}
                >
                  <StarBorderIcon />
                </IconButton>
              }
              actionPosition="left"
            />
          </ImageListItem>
        );
      })}
    </ImageList>
  );
}

const itemData = [
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551963831-b3b1ca40c98e',
    title: 'Breakfast',
    author: '@bkristastucchio',
    featured: true,
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551782450-a2132b4ba21d',
    title: 'Burger',
    author: '@rollelflex_graphy726',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522770179533-24471fcdba45',
    title: 'Camera',
    author: '@helloimnik',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1444418776041-9c7e33cc5a9c',
    title: 'Coffee',
    author: '@nolanissac',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533827432537-70133748f5c8',
    title: 'Hats',
    author: '@hjrc33',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558642452-9d2a7deb7f62',
    title: 'Honey',
    author: '@arwinneil',
    featured: true,
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516802273409-68526ee1bdd6',
    title: 'Basketball',
    author: '@tjdragotta',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518756131217-31eb79b20e8f',
    title: 'Fern',
    author: '@katie_wasserman',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597645587822-e99fa5d45d25',
    title: 'Mushrooms',
    author: '@silverdalex',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567306301408-9b74779a11af',
    title: 'Tomato basil',
    author: '@shelleypauls',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1471357674240-e1a485acb3e1',
    title: 'Sea star',
    author: '@peterlaster',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589118949245-7d38baf380d6',
    title: 'Bike',
    author: '@southside_customs',
  },
];
```

Comment: You can use a simple container (e.g. React fragment: `<>...</>`) and put multiple `<IconButton>`s there.

Comment: I found out you're correct! I did not know this. If you add this as an answer, I'll happily give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `actionIcon` prop on the `<ImageListItemBar>` component is a `node`, so you can put any valid JSX in there, and in your case making a simple container with multiple `<IconButtons>` should work:

```
actionIcon={
  <>
    <IconButton
      key="star"
      sx={{ color: "white" }}
      aria-label={`star ${item.title}`}
    >
      <StarBorderIcon />
    </IconButton>
    <IconButton
      key="heart"
      sx={{ color: "white" }}
      aria-label={`favorite ${item.title}`}
    >
      <FavoriteBorderIcon />
    </IconButton>
  </>
}
```

For a working example you can refer to this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-customimagelist-with-multiple-icons-wqdrzp).